What factors cause differences between dried herb/spice brands?
Just bought some sainsburys brand dried ginger and noticed the quality was very different from some batts brand dried ginger which I already had in the cupboard for some time.
The difference in eating the raw herbs was so much it made me think the brand is important.
Just wondering what factors cause the significant difference?  Some might say exposure to air as well as time but I’m also wondering about things like if these products have had toxins, additives etc added to them which may effect the final product as well as any other factors because the difference was very noticeable to me.
In the case of ginger the batts was superior to sainsburys.  Are there any minimally processed brands on the high street that might be worth considering if you want to avoid the factors that come into play?
Thanks.

Any additives should be listed on the jar label. (Why would anyone deliberately add a toxin?)

Age and how it's stored is a major issue, but spices are an agricultural product and so can vary greatly by the specific cultivar/strain being grown, and the growing conditions.
For instance, consider the wide variation in coffee, even though there are only two main types of coffee beans.  Chocolate and grapes (for wine) are also regularly sold by country of origin, but most herbs and spices are not.
A few of the exceptions are black pepper, vanilla beans, and cinnamon.  But it can get confusing because some some country/location names are more about the plant species/cultivar than specifically where it's grown (Chinese chives, Japanese eggplant, Mexican oregano, etc)
And countries are still huge places... something grown in an area that gets more or less rain, if the rain is early or late in the growing season, if it gets early or late sun, how cold the nights are, how well the soil drains, etc can all affect how the plant grows and the final quality of the spice or herb.  (what the wine folks call 'terroir')
And yes, there can be pollutants.  There was an article published yesterday reporting on a Consumer Reports study of lead levels in cinnamon: Only 6 Cinnamon Brands Were Deemed Safe for Consumption, According to a New Investigation by Consumer Reports.  It varied from 0.02 to 3.52 ppm (parts per million)

I also forgot to mention the issue with nutrients in the soil that can dramatically change the resulting plant.  'Vidalia onions' are special because that region has lower sulfur levels in their soil.  Even pests can affect the plants (insects cause some to produce compounds to protect themselves, some of which we want)

For dried herbs, lot depends on the variety. For example there are many different varieties of cinnamon, some are sweeter and more flavoursome than others. Unfortunately brands do not need to disclose the variety of the original plant they use, so it's a bit of trial and error.
As a rule of thumb, the more you pay, the better the quality. Except Schwartz, which IMHO isn't worth it.
However ginger is interesting in that the dried variety has a completely different flavour profile to the fresh. I just mention this as you said something about "The difference in eating the raw herbs". That's an exception though.
See Fresh, cooked or dried ginger: How to differentiate in aromas and flavours.

You could make the URL you included into a clickable link by adding a space between it and the . at the end of the previous sentence.

There are a lot of factors which cause a huge variation in quality.

Cultivar - different herb cultivars have a different taste
Growing conditions - usually, cheaply grown herbs from a crowded greenhouse don't have much aroma.
Storage - if not stored properly, the aroma dissipates
Age - the aroma goes away with age
Fraud - I've read investigations where it turned out that fraud is pretty common in herbs and spices. The typical methods is to bulk it up with harmless but cheap substances (e.g. adding dried blackberry leaves to dried leafy herbs) and to extract the aroma from the raw material (e.g. for selling as essential oils), then sell the spent material as if it were still containing all its aromatics. I don't remember reading cases where toxic material was added; that wouldn't be in the interest of the seller, since it would be more likely to be discovered, more likely to lead to sanctions if discovered, and not cheaper than adding harmless stuff.

Any of these can contribute to a difference between brands, or between batches of the same brand. And you don't have indications for any of them before buying. So really, the only thing you can go on is brand reputation - which is not the same thing as the ability to get a contract with a large supermarket chain and thus become ubiquitous. Basically, you have to find out for yourself, or from word of mouth of trusted individuals, which brands have consistently good quality.

You're right along with adding addictives there can be several other factors as well including the source of ingredients significantly influences phytochemical composition and flavor, as variations in soil, climate, and agricultural practices affect the bioactive compounds present. Processing methods also play a crucial role like high-temperature drying can lead to the degradation of volatile oils, while lower-temperature methods preserve flavor. Additionally, the presence of additives and preservatives may alter sensory characteristics, and exposure to air, light, and moisture can further degrade quality over time. Finally, quality control standards practiced by brands impact the overall integrity of the product.
Sources - 1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9777633/
2. https://kerone.com/blog/drying-methods-for-improving-the-quality-of-dried-herbs/
3. https://www.sairem.com/the-different-industrial-drying-technologies/
